# Found user 'l_certSignSmDetach' in security logins and don't know what it is for

Tags: sql-server

I was working in my local instance of Microsoft sql server management studio today when I noticed a user that I don't remember seeing before named `l_certSignSmDetach`.  It didn't appear to have access to any individual database mapped to it (I frequently delete and restore dbs on this server so it's possible that whatever it was attached to has been since deleted).  I googled this username, and couldn't find anything helpful to indicate if it's supposed to be there.  I have disabled the access to the db engine and disabled the login.

Can anyone give me information on this username if it is in fact used for something helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [sp_Blitz® Change Log](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/changelog/):

> *Changes in v52 – June 2, 2016:*
>
> SQL Server 2016 compatibility. 2016 RTM ships with some questionable
>    database-level options like heaps in DWDiagnostics, target recovery
>     time changed in the DW* databases, and **l_certSignSmDetach as a new
>     default sysadmin login**, so ignoring those.

```
SELECT *
FROM master.sys.syslogins
WHERE sysadmin = 1
  AND name = 'l_certSignSmDetach';
```

Comment: Would you be so kind as to put this in some context for me?  as in, am I reading this correctly saying that sp_Blitz is saying that this user was shipped with sql server 2016 compatibility, and it should be ignored / safely deleted?

Comment: @TedDelezene I would ignore it(alternatively disable and leave it).